# Meta property criterion on the internal language of a topos of sheaves for Noetherianity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, topos-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. Then $X$ is irreducible if and only if in the internal language of $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$, $\bot$ is not true and we have one side of De Morgan's law, that is, for all formulae $\phi,\psi$, we have $\neg(\phi \land \psi) \Rightarrow \neg\phi \lor \neg\psi$. (Proposition 7.9 of "Using the internal language of toposes in algebraic geometry'' by Blechschmidt.)

I was wondering if we have an analogous result describing when $X$ is Noetherian, in terms of a "nice" meta property of the internal language of $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$? I am unable to find it in Blechschmidt's paper, nor on nLab.